# How to get previous months ranges in postgres

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to get date ranges of the last 12 months starting from now.

however as month's days are not the same, I am wondering if it is possible to compute those dates on database level or if I have to compute the values outside and pass them as variables.

for example we are in September I need

```
'september', ["2020-09-01 00:00:00+00","2020-10-01 00:00:00+00"]
'august', ["2020-08-01 00:00:00+00","2020-09-01 00:00:00+00"]
'july', ["2020-07-01 00:00:00+00","2020-08-01 00:00:00+00"]
'june', ["2020-06-01 00:00:00+00","2020-07-01 00:00:00+00"]
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc()` with the `month` parameter to adjust for variations of weeks among months.

```sql
SELECT
  to_char(now() - series.n * '1 month'::interval, 'month') AS "month",
  tstzrange(
    date_trunc('month', now()) - series.n * '1 month'::interval,
    date_trunc('month', now()) - (series.n - 1) * '1 month'::interval,
    '[]'
  ) AS range_dates
FROM (
  SELECT generate_series(0, 11) AS n
) AS series
```

Produces:

```
'september',["2020-09-01 00:00:00+00","2020-10-01 00:00:00+00"]
'august', ["2020-08-01 00:00:00+00","2020-09-01 00:00:00+00"]
'july', ["2020-07-01 00:00:00+00","2020-08-01 00:00:00+00"]
'june', ["2020-06-01 00:00:00+00","2020-07-01 00:00:00+00"]
'may', ["2020-05-01 00:00:00+00","2020-06-01 00:00:00+00"]
'april', ["2020-04-01 00:00:00+00","2020-05-01 00:00:00+00"]
'march', ["2020-03-01 00:00:00+00","2020-04-01 00:00:00+00"]
'february', ["2020-02-01 00:00:00+00","2020-03-01 00:00:00+00"]
'january', ["2020-01-01 00:00:00+00","2020-02-01 00:00:00+00"]
'december', ["2019-12-01 00:00:00+00","2020-01-01 00:00:00+00"]
'november', ["2019-11-01 00:00:00+00","2019-12-01 00:00:00+00"]
'october', ["2019-10-01 00:00:00+00","2019-11-01 00:00:00+00"]
```

Comment: I need the months dates not the weeks, I edited the question to remove misleading part of weeks, I am trying to get the date ranges of last 12months

Comment: @bihireboris You should edit the question to post a table of results you're trying to produce. Also, in `generate_series(0, 3)`, you can change the `3` to a greater number and that will produce more weeks and ranges.

Comment: could you kindly take a look on the edit, I put the type of ranges I need